# How can i add subcategories against main categories id in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to add categories programatically. Here is my code:

```
<?php
function stringtourlKey($collectionName, $separator = '-')
    {
        $accents_regex = '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i';
        $special_cases = array('&' => 'and');
        $string = mb_strtolower(trim($collectionName), 'UTF-8');
        $string = str_replace(array_keys($special_cases), array_values($special_cases), $string);
        $string = preg_replace($accents_regex, '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/u", "$separator", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[$separator]+/u", "$separator", $string);
        return trim($string, "-");
    }

$allGenre   =   array(
                    "Suits & Suit Separates",
                    "Shirts",
                    "Pants",
                    "Sportcoats & Blazers",
                    "Swimwear",
                    "Athletic Clothing",
                    "Loungewear",
                    "Outerwear",
                    "Underwear","All Clothing"
                );

foreach($allGenre as $categoryStr) {
    $collectionName = $categoryStr;

    $urlKey = stringtourlKey($collectionName);

    try {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setName($collectionName);
        $category->setUrlKey($urlKey);
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
        $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(205);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
        $var = $category->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
?>
```

But through this script, one by one I'm trying to add categories and then pass sub category `id` then play script one by one. I want to add categories and their subcategories against his id at one time, is that possible or anyone have like that script. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think it works like $testingFlow = array( "first" => array("Monitors", "Oversized Displays", "Monitor Accessories")); in this way, but don't know how set foreach, anyone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution of my question :-)

```
function stringtourlKey($collectionName, $separator = '-'){
          $accents_regex = '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i';
          $special_cases = array('&' => 'and');
          $string = mb_strtolower(trim($collectionName), 'UTF-8');
          $string = str_replace(array_keys($special_cases), array_values($special_cases), $string);
          $string = preg_replace($accents_regex, '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
          $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/u", "$separator", $string);
          $string = preg_replace("/[$separator]+/u", "$separator", $string);
          return trim($string, "-");
        }

"Home Improvement"                  =>  array("Storage & Organization", "Sinks", "Faucets"),
"Bath"                              =>  array("Bath Accessories", "Vanities")


foreach($array as $parent => $vals){
        $collectionName = $parent;

        $urlKey = stringtourlKey($collectionName);

try{
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setName($collectionName);
        $category->setUrlKey($urlKey);
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
        $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(14080);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());

        $var = $category->save();
        $cat_id = $category->getId();

            if(is_array($vals)){
            foreach ($vals as $key => $child){

            $collectionName = $child;

                $urlKey = stringtourlKey($collectionName);

                try{
                    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                    $category->setName($collectionName);
                    $category->setUrlKey($urlKey);
                    $category->setIsActive(1);
                    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
                    $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
                    $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
                    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());

                    $var = $category->save();
                    }catch(Exception $e) {
                    var_dump($e);
                    }
                }
            }



        } catch(Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
        }
        }
```

and now it's working fine with just once play script, thanks to me :-P